# icons on top bar streched (Ubuntu 22.04 , gnome shell 42.5)

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and the additional icons from opened apps appear all weird in the top bar (see attached screenshot [stretched-icons-top-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrenZ.png)).
Also, Ive installed the add-on to remove the accessibility icon from the top bar through https://extensions.gnome.org/ (hide universal access) but every time i turn on the computer the icon is there and i must go to the website and click it off and on again for it to disappear (until next reboot)

How could I solve these two issues? Thanks!